# Can't figure out using Firebase to login with Github

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth, firebase

In my home page, I have a link to the following:

```
    <a href="/login">Login with Github</a>
```

And in my app.js I have the following:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  var ref = new Firebase('https://hrr-kitchen.firebaseio.com');

  ref.authWithOAuthPopup('github', function(err, authData) {
    console.log('in authWithOAuthPopup');
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.code);
    } else if (authData) {
      // user authenticated with GitHub
      console.log('User ID: ' + authData.uid);
    }
  });
});
```

I've spent hours on this searching on the web and I've tried  so many different things, that my eyes are loopy.  I'm thinking I may need to call a function from the html and put the code in a function and I'm tempted at this point to try and just  do it in javascript outside of the server, but I think that's janky.

I'm new to firebase and express and I just can't figure this out.  Please help?

EDIT:  I've been able to get something working by changing my HTML to look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ref = new Firebase('https://hrr-kitchen.firebaseio.com');

  githubLogin = function () {
    login(function(err, authData) {
      var username = authData.github.username;
    });
  };

  var login = function(cb) {
    ref.authWithOAuthPopup('github', cb, {
      remember: "sessionOnly"
    });
  };
</script>

<button onclick="githubLogin();">Login with Github</button>
```

But I really would like to figure out how to do it in express correctly!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authentication methods in the Firebase library only work on the client-side.

If you need to authenticate on the server, you should use `authWithCustomToken` from a generated token. [The Firebase docs have a detailed section on generating tokens](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html).

The real question though, is why do you need to authenticate with GitHub on the server? Firebase is designed to do nearly all of the development on the client.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up trashing the login through Firebase and used passport-github.  Thanks for the help!